# CSS hover event, Animation wont run

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, transition

I have a container that holds image holder and text holder.
I can set it so that on hover the image scales and the same for the text.
YET when I try so set the image holder hover to scale the image and a secondary action to scale the text, hover just doesnt do the animation .

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageholder"><img></div>
    <div class="textholder"><text></div>
</div>

CSS
.imageholder:hover .textholder{
    transform: translatey(100%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

heii, you can change your code like this :

```css
.imageholder:hover, .textholder:hover{
    transform: translatey(100%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageholder">this is image</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="textholder">this is a text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I realize that I did not clarify that I did not want the image to have the same transition, and that the image would activate the text. I thought that a sibling combinator would make the image activate the text. I can get them to activate on hover when I set them individually, yet when I set one to activate the next in line it doesn't run the animation.

Comment: I have it working in a text project but the animation hides(completely gone cant find) the text instead of easing out.

This example works: https://codepen.io/nikdane12/pen/qBYJMXW

Answer (score 0):

You need to add coma in your css like this:

```
.imageholder:hover, .textholder:hover{
    transform: translatey(100%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .5s ease;
 }
```